# Windows Universal (UWP) Charting Library

Tags: windows, xaml, charts, windows-10, uwp

Are there any charting/data visualization libraries out there that are compatible with the new UWP Windows 10 app framework, besides Telerik? I have come across many charting libraries out there, but none compatible with this new UWP project type.

Comment: Here is [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization) for Windows/Phone 8.1, you can create a UWP library, copy code, and rebuild. I already did it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SyncFusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp) has charting and it has a [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense) for open source projects.

Comment: Thanks. This is the type of thing I was looking for.